# Maximum feature limit with QGIS Server published WFS 1.0.0 / 1.1.0

Tags: wfs, qgis-server, getfeature, limitations

In configuring WFS servers, we may choose to set a **maximum feature limit** to be returned per Feature response. So when a maximum feature limit of 10,000 is configured for a WFS server and a feature query hits 20,000 features, only 10,000 features will be returned.

With QGIS Server **API WFS3**, we can use the `QGIS_SERVER_API_WFS3_MAX_LIMIT` which defaults to 10,000 ([see QGIS Server Guide 6.2](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/config.html)).

Do we have any such configuration for **WFS Version 1.0.0 / 1.1.0 published via QGIS Server**? How can we configure a maximum feature limit for QGIS Server WFS?
I have searched for texts such as `max` and `limit` in the WFS 1.0 and WFS 1.1 GetCapabilities, and looked through the [env variables of QGIS Server](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/server/qgsserversettings.h). I could only find the setting for API WFS3 though.

Comment: Certainly you will be able to test your service form the client side, by making appropriate requests. At a basic level you can write the requests manually and try in a browser.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Since testing is basic enough, I suggest you [Edit] the Question to focus on setting a limit on QGIS Server. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This question was improved and now is enough focused - in my opinion - and should be reopened.